# How to Connect To Bluetooth Devices Using MAC Address

Tags: macos, bluetooth, mac-address, rfcomm

Okay so this is my first experience working with Java or Android development in general, and I need to create an application that will allow me to connect to external bluetooth devices, such as a bluetooth headset, by entering the devices MAC address by prompting for it to be entered via the keyboard.

I understand that the BluetoothAdapter API has most of the functionality I am looking for but I am getting overwhelmed and having trouble integrating its features. I need to pair these devices without entering a pin code, so I was instructed to utilize 'ListenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord' but I am really unsure of how to implement this, and how BluetoothAdapter, BluetoothSocket, BluetoothServerSocket, and BluetoothDevice all tie in together here. I've found plenty of examples of people connected to previously paired devices automatically using getBondedDevices to get their MAC addresses, but none where the user enters the MAC address of the device they would like to connect to.

Anyway, here is my code below for my app thus far. It will turn bluetooth on if it is off and make the phone discoverable for 120 seconds. It will also say what devices it discovered in range, but I want to remove this in favor of just prompting for the MAC address if the device you want to connect to.

To give some context as to what this app will be used for: there is a service running on the phone that takes input from the built in barcode scanner and puts it into text fields in the forefront activity. So the users of these phones will have a whole bunch of bluetooth headsets available to connect to, and I would like them to open this app, turn on the phones bluetooth, scan the MAC address of the headset they want to connect to thats on a barcode either on the bluetooth headset or its charging cradle, and be able to disconnect from it later. I followed a tutorial and my code below has some functionality now that I would like to change or remove: no listing previous paired devices, no pairing to the last paired device, etc. Only pairing through manually entered (or a scanned barcode) of the MAC address.

Any help would be appreciated, I am completely lost at how to do this... Can pay via paypal for some assistance if someone could just work with me long enough to figure this out. I am so close as it is I feel...

```
package com.android.settings.bluetoothheadset;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadset;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;




public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
protected static final int DISCOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;

public TextView statusUpdate;
public Button connect;
public Button disconnect;
public ImageView logo;
public String toastText = "";
private BluetoothDevice remoteDevice;


BroadcastReceiver bluetoothState = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String prevStateExtra = BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE;
        String stateExtra = BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE;
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(stateExtra, -1);
        int previousState = intent.getIntExtra(prevStateExtra, -1);
        //String toastText = "";
        switch (state) {
            case (BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON): {
                toastText = "Bluetooth turning on";
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case (BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON): {
                toastText = "Bluetooth on";
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setupUI();
                break;
            }
            case (BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF): {
                toastText = "Bluetooth turning off";
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case (BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF): {
                toastText = "Bluetooth is off";
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setupUI();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupUI();
}


private void setupUI() {
    final TextView statusUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    final Button connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);
    final Button disconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnectBtn);
    final ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);


    disconnect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    logo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        String address = btAdapter.getAddress();
        String name = btAdapter.getName();
        String statusText = name + " : " + address;
        statusUpdate.setText(statusText);
        disconnect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        connect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        connect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        statusUpdate.setText("Bluetooth is not on");
    }

    connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //String actionStateChanged = BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED;
            //String actionRequestEnable = BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE;
            //IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(actionStateChanged);
            //registerReceiver(bluetoothState, filter);
            //startActivityForResult(new Intent(actionRequestEnable), 0);

            String scanModeChanged = BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED;
            String beDiscoverable = BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE;
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(scanModeChanged);
            registerReceiver(bluetoothState, filter);
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(beDiscoverable), DISCOVERY_REQUEST);

        }
    });

    disconnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btAdapter.disable();
            disconnect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            logo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            connect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            statusUpdate.setText("Bluetooth Off");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == DISCOVERY_REQUEST) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Discovery enabled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setupUI();
        findDevices();
    }
}

private void findDevices() {
    String lastUsedRemoteDevice = getLastUsedRemoteBTDevice();
    if (lastUsedRemoteDevice != null) {
        toastText = "Checking for known paired devices, namely: " + lastUsedRemoteDevice;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        for (BluetoothDevice pairedDevice : pairedDevices) {
            if (pairedDevice.getAddress().equals(lastUsedRemoteDevice)) {
                toastText = "Found Device: " + pairedDevice.getName() + "@" + lastUsedRemoteDevice;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                remoteDevice = pairedDevice;
            }

        }
    }

    if (remoteDevice == null) {
        toastText = "Starting discovery for remote devices...";
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (btAdapter.startDiscovery()) {
            toastText = "Discovery thread started...Scanning for Devices";
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            registerReceiver(discoveryResult, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));


        }
    }
}

BroadcastReceiver discoveryResult = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String remoteDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);
        BluetoothDevice remoteDevice;
        remoteDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        toastText = "Discovered: " + remoteDeviceName;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //statusUpdate.setText(statusText);
    }
};

private String getLastUsedRemoteBTDevice() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String result = prefs.getString("LAST_REMOTE_DEVICE_ADDRESS", null);
    return result;
}
}
```